# I cant see my bones in, parent-child of option

Tags: rigging

I want to set the target to my hands for magazine and then select the Main bone as a bone. But no I cant see any of the bones in that option 
... Any kind of help will be appreciated

[image]

Comment: the bone called "Main" must not be part of the armature called "Hands"

Comment: So, what should I do?
Edit: Thats a stupid question I know... Im just trying to do a reload animation. If something happens I'll let you know if you want to help me and stuff. Have a nice day! Thank you!

Comment: in the first field, called Target, you need to choose the name of the armature that contains the bone that you want to make parent. In the second field, called Bone, you need to choose the bone itself, the one that you want to make parent. If Main is not part of the armature called Hands, Blender can't find it... so I guess Main is not part of Hands.